# Loading data directly from BigQuery to Orange

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, orange

I would like to ask you if there is possibility in Orange to load to it data directly eg. from BigQuery? I added block "Python script" to the flow and my script looks like that:

```py
import os
import sys
import Orange


os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'path toapplication_default_credentials.json'

from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import secretmanager
bigquery_client = google.cloud.bigquery.Client(project='my project')
secret_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
query ="""

my query

"""

query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)

out_data = query_job
```

I was trying to put also Orange.data.Table on query_job but it is not working. How can I load data directly from Python to orange?